# Individual click handlers in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I'm generating a list with the following code:

```
      <li class="list-group-item border" v-for="command in commands" :key="command">
        <div v-if="!command.args">
          <h3>{{ command.name }}</h3>
          <small>{{ command.desc }}</small>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <button @click="toggleActive">{{ command.name }}</button>
          <small>{{ command.desc }}</small>
          <div class="args" v-if="active" v-for="(argDesc, argName) in command.args" :key="argName, argDesc">
            <hr>
            <p>{{ argName }}</p>
            <small>{{ argDesc }}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

using the following data:

```
  commands: {
    foo: { name: "foo", desc: "bar" },
    lorem: {
      name: "lorem",
      desc: "ipsum",
      args: {
        place: "holder"
      }
    },
```

and the method:

```
  methods: {
    toggleActive: function(event) {
      let clickedButton = event.currentTarget;
      clickedButton.classList.toggle("active");
      if (this.active) {
        this.active = false;
      } else if (!this.active) {
        this.active = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

If there is a more elegant solution to this, I'd like to know but my real question is how can I make it so that the onclick event fires for the clicked button and not all of the generated buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have *one* `active` property for your whole instance.

One solution would be to add an `active` property to each of your `command`s and toggle it instead:

- Your click handler should be: `@click="toggleActive($event, command)"`
- And your method should set `command.active` now, instead of `this.active`:

  ```js
  methods: {
    toggleActive: function(event, command) {   // added command arg
      // removed manual class toggling (see "Bonus" below)
      if (command.active) {                    // command.active instead of this.active
        command.active = false;                // command.active instead of this.active
      } else if (!command.active) {
        Vue.set(command, 'active', true);      // using `Vue.set()`  because `active`
      }                                        // was not initially in `data()`
    }
  }
  ```
- Finally, your `v-if` should reference each command: `v-if="command.active"`.
- **Bonus:** With Vue you shouldn't have to do `clickedButton.classList.toggle("active");` directly. You can just bind the `class` attribute: `:class="{active: command.active}"`.

Demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    commands: {
      foo: { name: "foo", desc: "bar" },
      lorem: {
        name: "lorem",
        desc: "ipsum",
        args: {
          place: "holder"
        }
      },
      aaa: {
        name: "aaa",
        desc: "bbb",
        args: {
          place: "ccc"
        }
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive: function(event, command) {
      // removed manual class toggling in favor of :class="{active: command.active}"
      if (command.active) {
        command.active = false;
      } else if (!command.active) {
        Vue.set(command, 'active', true);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <li class="list-group-item border" v-for="command in commands" :key="command.name">
    <div v-if="!command.args">
      <h3>{{ command.name }}</h3>
      <small>{{ command.desc }}</small>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <button @click="toggleActive($event, command)" :class="{active: command.active}">{{ command.name }}</button>
      <small>{{ command.desc }}</small>
      <div class="args" v-if="command.active" v-for="(argDesc, argName) in command.args" :key="argName, argDesc">
        <hr>
        <p>{{ argName }}</p>
        <small>{{ argDesc }}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Another option, if you don't want to change each `command` is to turn `active` into a map of flags (instead of just one flag):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: {}, // should be an object
    commands: {
      foo: { name: "foo", desc: "bar" },
      lorem: {
        name: "lorem",
        desc: "ipsum",
        args: {
          place: "holder"
        }
      },
      aaa: {
        name: "aaa",
        desc: "bbb",
        args: {
          place: "ccc"
        }
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive: function(event, command) {
      // removed manual class toggling in favor of :class="{active: active[command.name]}"
      if (this.active[command.name]) {
        this.active[command.name] = false;
      } else if (!this.active[command.name]) {
        Vue.set(this.active, command.name, true);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <li class="list-group-item border" v-for="command in commands" :key="command.name">
    <div v-if="!command.args">
      <h3>{{ command.name }}</h3>
      <small>{{ command.desc }}</small>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <button @click="toggleActive($event, command)" :class="{active: active[command.name]}">{{ command.name }}</button>
      <small>{{ command.desc }}</small>
      <div class="args" v-if="active[command.name]" v-for="(argDesc, argName) in command.args" :key="argName, argDesc">
        <hr>
        <p>{{ argName }}</p>
        <small>{{ argDesc }}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```